# How to restart apache of CentOS7 periodically

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7

I need to restart appache under Cent OS 7 1 time per day.

How I can programm/script it?

Bascially I do it manually like

> /bin/sysemctl restart httpd.service

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your script via a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

For this, add this to your crontab-file:

```sh
59 23 * * * /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
```

This will execute `/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service` one time at 23:59 every day of every week of every month.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the **cron** solution is certainly the best option, you can also use some **Systemd** directives to get almost the same result.
As **root**, create the **/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d** directory:

> mkdir /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
>   cd /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d

Create the **restart.conf** file and paste the following lines into it:

> [Service]
>   WatchdogSec=1day
>   Restart=always

You now need to restart the global daemon configuration:

> systemctl daemon-reload

Finally, you have to restart the **httpd** service:

> systemctl restart httpd

Every day the watchdog timer will interrupt the **httpd** daemon and **Systemd** will restart it just after.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `cron` installed (you should have it anyway), do `crontab -e` and put the command:

```
minute   hour   day   month   dayofweek   command # this part is provided by crontab, just for reference.
0 0 * * * /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
```